# Retrieving data from a virtualbox instance that refuses to boot

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I have a Windows 7 VM in VirtualBox running on a Windows 7 host, but recently it no longer would boot.

Is there a way to retrieve the data stored on the harddrive somehow?

Comment: Sure: just mount the virtual hard disk. What's your host OS? What virtual drive format did you use?

Comment: Host OS is also windows 7. Drive is Dynamically allocated storage on SATA with type AHCI. VDI file format

Comment: Why does it not boot? Perhaps easier to fix that issue, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recover data, all you need to do is mount the virtual drive on a working system - the same principle as physical recovery.

You say your host OS is Windows. Your options are:

- Since your issue is simply an inability to boot, you could mount a Linux live image or the Windows installation image (in the optical drive) and boot from that. That should let you read the data off the disk. I'd recommend Linux here, since the Windows pre-installation environment is rather limited - namely, you'll have trouble copying files off the guest.

  Heck, you could try to recover the damaged guest OS.
- Or create another VM (Windows or Linux are both fine) and set up the OS on a fresh drive. Then you can attach/mount the VDI as a secondary drive.
- Or look for third-party tools capable of mounting VDI files (e.g. WinMount, not free)
- Or convert to VHD, which Windows can natively mount. Possibly risky.